# Cannot execute python script on Raspberry Pi startup

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, rc

I'm having problems with starting a python script on Raspberry Pi boot. I have read many threads and tried some tricks, however, none of them worked for me.

The file I am trying to execute is named *test.py*, it just logs a time to another file, when was Pi's startup:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time

f=open('logger.txt','w')
tim=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
f.write('Startup on: %s\n'%(tim))
f.close()
```

It is located in: */home/pi* and I modified the privileges to all (777). I tried to add a line to */etc/rc.local* file before exit 0, my *rc.local* looks like that:

```
python /home/pi/test.py &
exit 0
```

Nothing happens on the startup. If I write a .sh file with the same function and change the line in *rc.local* accordingly, everything works fine.

Could anyone please help me, what is that different in running python script on startup? Thank you, Kaki

Comment: can you try to give the absolute path of your file? I know that it is a long shot but if it works for .sh maybe python does something different. so it should be /home/pi/logger.txt

Comment: Which OS is installed on your Raspberry?

Comment: I have Raspbian. Okay, I'll try to specify the absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify absolute path, `open` assume relative path to current working directory.

You'd better to try use absolute path first, before you know where the working directory is.

```
f = open('/home/pi/logger.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Ok, it was really my bad with the missing absolute path in python script. Thank you very much!